# Downloading a large Blob to local file in ManifestV3 service worker

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a logging mechanism in place that saves the logs into an array. And I need a way to download the logs into a file.

I had this previously working (on manifest v2) with

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(reallyLongString, { type: 'text/plain' }));
const filename = 'logs.txt';
chrome.downloads.download({url, filename});
```

Now I am migrating to manifest v3 and since manifest v3 does not have `URL.createObjectURL`, you cannot create a url to pass to `chrome.downloads.download`

Instead it is possible to create a Blob URL using something like

```
const url = `data:text/plain,${reallyLongString}`; 
const filename = 'logs.txt';
chrome.downloads.download({url, filename});
```

**The problem** is that `chrome.downloads.download` seems to have a limit on the number of characters passed in the url argument, and the downloaded file only contains a small part of the string.

So what would be a way to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, a way to download Blob directly in service worker will be implemented in https://crbug.com/1224027.

#### Workaround via Offscreen document

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77427098

It uses chrome.offscreen API to start an invisible DOM page where we can call URL.createObjectURL, pass the result back to SW that will use it for chrome.downloads.download.

#### Workaround via an extension page

Here's the algorithm:

1. Use an already opened page such as popup or options
2. Otherwise, inject an iframe into any page that we have access to
3. Otherwise, open a new minimized window

```js
async function downloadBlob(blob, name, destroyBlob = true) {
  // When `destroyBlob` parameter is true, the blob is transferred instantly,
  // but it's unusable in SW afterwards, which is fine as we made it only to download
  const send = async (dst, close) => {
    dst.postMessage({blob, name, close}, destroyBlob ? [await blob.arrayBuffer()] : []);
  };
  // try an existing page/frame
  const [client] = await self.clients.matchAll({type: 'window'});
  if (client) return send(client);
  const WAR = chrome.runtime.getManifest().web_accessible_resources;
  const tab = WAR?.some(r => r.resources?.includes('downloader.html'))
    && (await chrome.tabs.query({url: '*://*/*'})).find(t => t.url);
  if (tab) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      func: () => {
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('downloader.html');
        iframe.style.cssText = 'display:none!important';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      }
    });
  } else {
    chrome.windows.create({url: 'downloader.html', state: 'minimized'});
  }
  self.addEventListener('message', function onMsg(e) {
    if (e.data === 'sendBlob') {
      self.removeEventListener('message', onMsg);
      send(e.source, !tab);
    }
  });
}
```

downloader.html:

```html
<script src=downloader.js></script>
```

downloader.js, popup.js, options.js, and other scripts for extension pages (not content scripts):

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(swr => swr.active.postMessage('sendBlob'));
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = async e => {
  if (e.data.blob) {
    await chrome.downloads.download({
      url: URL.createObjectURL(e.data.blob),
      filename: e.data.name,
    });
  }
  if (e.data.close) {
    window.close();
  }
}
```

manifest.json:

```json
"web_accessible_resources": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "resources": ["downloader.html"],
  "use_dynamic_url": true
}]
```

**Warning!** Since `"use_dynamic_url": true` is [not yet implemented](https://crbug.com/1133624) don't add web_accessible_resources if you don't want to make your extension detectable by web pages.