# How to download a PDF in a custom chrome extension using offscreen document

Tags: google-chrome-extension, blob, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Because of the size of my generated PDF, the base64 conversion is not possible and I have to use the offscreen functionality.

Based on this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/75539867/8016254

I tried to download a PDF file that will be reated in my custom chrome extension.

background.js

```
import './pdf-lib.min.js';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    (async () => {
        if (message.pdfUrls && message.pdfUrls.length > 0) {
            // Debug PDF
            const urls = ["https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"];
            await mergeAllPDFs(urls, "Test");
        }
    })();

    return true;
});
async function mergeAllPDFs(urls, filename) {
    const numDocs = urls.length;
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
    for (let i = 0; i < numDocs; i++) {
        console.log(`Fetching ${urls[i]}`)
        const donorPdf = await fetch(urls[i]);
        const donorPdfBytes = await donorPdf.arrayBuffer();
        const donorPdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(donorPdfBytes);
        const copiedPages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(donorPdfDoc, donorPdfDoc.getPageIndices());
        copiedPages.forEach((page) => pdfDoc.addPage(page));
    }
    const pdfDocBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    const waiting = await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
        url: 'offscreen.html',
        reasons: ['BLOBS'],
        justification: 'reason for needing the document',
    });
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        data: pdfDocBytes
    }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const url = response.url;
        console.log(url);
        chrome.downloads.download({
            url: url,
            filename: filename + ".pdf"
        });
    });

}
```

offscreen.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const blob = new Blob([message.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    sendResponse({ url: url });
    return true;
});
```

The resulting PDF seems to be corrupt and way smaller than expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem: chrome.runtime.sendMessage can't send binary data in Chrome.

Solution: use standard web messaging.

// background

```js
await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({url: 'offscreen.html', /*....*/});
const clientUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('offscreen.html');
const client = (await clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true}))
  .find(c => c.url === clientUrl);
const mc = new MessageChannel();
client.postMessage(blob, [mc.port2]);
const {data: blobUrl} = await new Promise(cb => (mc.port1.onmessage = cb));
chrome.downloads.download({
  url: blobUrl,
  filename: filename + '.pdf',
});
```

// offscreen.js

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = e => {
  e.ports[0].postMessage(URL.createObjectURL(e.data));
  setTimeout(close);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for that I didn't think of that. I tried to use it but no message will be send, is there anything that I missed?

Comment: OK I tried pretty much everything. Even a kind of different approach like here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107232/messagechannel-port-postmessages-data-is-null-when-calling-postmessage-with-a-t)

It feels like either the message is not being sent, or the receiving part is not working. There is no way to debug this I think. 

Does the offscreen document allow you to have a "window"?

Comment: Yeah I know, I added multiple console.logs. I can see that the code is stuck at this part:
`const {data: blobUrl} = await new Promise(cb => (mc.port1.onmessage = cb));`
And in the offline document no message has been received, So either the sending part is not working or the receiver is not working. Thank you  for your help though. The idea is pretty good, but I still feel like the extension has some limitations to MessageChannels. Is something missing in my manifest? Do I need to add some priviliges?

Comment: Sorry I didn't test the code. I fixed the mistake now.

Comment: No need to say sorry. The transmission works perfectly now :)
Thank you!

Comment: May I ask which resources you used for that? Espacially the `includeUncontrolled: true` part. I was not able to find similar solutions. Really interesting stuff hapenning here :)

Comment: I use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/matchAll). The need for includeUncontrolled seems to be due to a bug in Chrome as it doesn't list the offscreen document otherwise.