# Issue with Chrome Extension Manifest Version 3:Downloading URLs of All Tabs as JSON

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is the code

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log('Extension Installed');
});

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
  console.log('Extension Started');
});

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});

  const tabsInfo = tabs.map(tab => ({
    title : tab.title,
    url:tab.url}));
    console.log('tabsInfo',tabsInfo);
    

    saveTextToFile(tabsInfo, 'extension_data.txt');
  


});

function saveTextToFile(text, filename) {
  const blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });

  const url = chrome.runtime.getURL(filename);

  chrome.downloads.download({
    url: url,
    filename: filename,
    conflictAction: 'prompt',
    saveAs: true
  });
}
```

[When It tries downloading the json file it gets the following message from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9opR.png)

The chrome extension should have been able to download the urls of all the tabs, save them and download them as a json file.Save the json file locally.I'm using manifest version 3.

Comment: 1) The API can't download blobs, you need to convert it first e.g. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77427098), 2) Remove chrome.runtime.getURL.